# Updating application from Android Market

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I have downloaded and installed an app from Android Market. Now I want to know how to update this apk installed in my device. Is this app updated by Android Market? Will it update automatically or do I need to update it manually?

Answer (score 3):

Market > My App > (an app) > [check] allow automatic updating

Comment: Yes , I got it .

Comment: @Nandlal Virani, so.... give a check.... XD

Comment: That's fine if you **want** automatic updates. For the vast majority of apps, you probably don't.

Comment: @Dante: Nandlal will not be able to accept this as an answer unless and until he/she creates an account here on Android Enthusiasts and "associates" it with the Stack Overflow account that originally wrote this question.

Comment: @Al Everett, I see. It's OK. All the conversation before you happened on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Android Market APKs are monitored, and you'll be notified when an update is available.  There should also be a checkbox on the Market page for each of them allowing you to specify automatic updating; the developer has a case-by-case override for that for when it might lead to loss of data.

Comment: Thanks Geekosaur ,Now I have got all information regarding Android Market .

Comment: Additionally, apps will not auto-update when their permissions have changed.  This is to prevent you from being harmed by an app that was previously safe and suddenly the new version has access to everything on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Play Store App and select "Update All" to do it manually should you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to update from the app store :

**1. Update Manually**
You can just search your app and if there is an update, there will be an `Update` button to click. It will download your file and install it automatically.

**2. Automatic Update**
This option will update all app that **doesn't** need extra permissions.
To simply turn on automatic update, just tap the three bars on the left of the search box, scroll down and hit the `Setting` button.
You'll see a lot of option that you can enable / disable. To enable the automatic update, select `Auto-update apps` and select what criteria the phone must reach when the update begins.

**3. Update all apps at the same time**
This option will update all the app in one time. This option will ask you about extra permission that your apps need.
To update all, just slide your finger from the very left of the screen to the middle and hit `My apps`. From there, you should see `Update all` button if there is 2 or more update available for download.